# How to send the result of a sql statement to a for loop using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to send the sql result to a for loop. I am new to spark and python, please help.

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
#bank = hive_context.table("cip_utilities.file_upload_temp")
data=hive_context.sql("select * from cip_utilities.cdm_variable_dict")
hive_context.sql("describe cip_utilities.cdm_variables_dict").registerTempTable("schema_def")
temp_data=hive_context.sql("select * from schema_def")
temp_data.show()
data1=hive_context.sql("select col_name from schema_def where data_type<>'string'")
data1.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`DataFrame.collect()` method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame), which aggregates the result of `Spark-SQL` query from all *executors* into *driver*.
- The `collect()` method will return a `Python` `list`, each element of which is a `Spark` `Row`
- You can then iterate over this list in a `for`-loop

---

Code snippet:

```
data1 = hive_context.sql("select col_name from schema_def where data_type<>'string'")
colum_names_as_python_list_of_rows = data1.collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to ask yourself *why* you want to iterate over the data.

Are you doing an aggregation? Transforming the data? If so, consider doing it using the spark API.

Printing some text? If so, then use .collect() and retrieve the data back to your driver process. Then you can loop over the result in the usual python way.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to find the maximum, minimum , standard deviation. Thats why need to send each col name in an iteration

Comment: You should be using the inbuilt spark functions to do that - it will be far more performant. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData